# Customizing model-stored validation rules in Laravel

Tags: php, validation, model, laravel

Let's say, I have a User model in Laravel like this:

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    public static $rules = array(
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:8|confirmed',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required|min:8'
    );

    ...

}
```

Rules, stored in model, will be reused both for login and register forms but problem occurs when there's no need for password confirmation (e.g. login form). And  there could be many such situations where the rules should be changed.

So, is there any pure method how to modify model-stored validation rules for different cases in Laravel?
Do I have to reorganize my rule storage approach at all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add rules dynamically when you need them.

For example:

If I am right, you only need the `password_confirmation` rule when registering a user and when updating a password. So, in your model, do not add the `password_confirmation` rule .

```
public static $rules = array(
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:8|confirmed'

}
```

How to add the rule dynamically:

To register a user, the `password_confirmation` field is required. So, from your controller, you can always add rules like the following:

```
$rules = User::$rules;

$rules['password_confirmation'] = 'required|min:8';
```

and sometimes you may need to add rules based on user input.

For example:

If a user selects `Australia` as country, they must also select a state.

```
$v = Validator::make($data, $rules ));
$v->sometimes('state', 'required', function($input)
{
   return $input->country == 'Australia';
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Dynamical adding of rules is great idea, however it does not provide a possibility to add/remove specific rules for specific fields! For example, the field `password` has rule `confirmed` (defined in model) but this rule must be removed when password confirmation is not needed!

Comment: You can't add or remove specific rules, but you can set the rule over again before you use it.  `$rules['password'] = 'required|min:8';`

Answer (score 11):

Late to the game but per Laravel docs you can use a 'sometimes' rule.

http://laravel.com/docs/validation

In brief:
In some situations, you may wish to run validation checks against a field only if that field is present in the input array. To quickly accomplish this, add the sometimes rule to your rule list:

```
    'password_confirmation' => 'sometimes|required|min:8|confirmed'
```

Answer (score 10):

I do something like this.

In the Model:

```
public static $rules = [
    'create' => [
        'first_name' => 'min:3',
        'last_name'  => 'min:3',
        'email'      => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'password'   => 'required|min:5|confirmed'
        ],
    'edit'   => [
        'first_name' => 'other',
        'last_name'  => 'other',
        'email'      => 'other',
        'password'   => 'other|min:5'
        ]
     ];
```

In the Controller:

```
$validator = Validator::make( $input, User::$rules['edit'] ); # Or User::$rules['create']

if ( $validator->fails() ) { code }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can see the Ardent Package handles model validation well for Laravel > 5.0. It appears to supoort all of the built-in validation features (such as the use of 'sometimes' when you only want to validate a field if it's passed) as well as extending them.

http://packalyst.com/packages/package/laravelbook/ardent